# arranging for python's sorted(set( <collection> ))

Tags: python

I'm trying to eliminate duplicates of an array containing a few thousands of custom objects.
For this I'm implementing the `__hash__` and `__cmp__` functions for these objects.

Is it safe to delegate these functions to one of the objects' fields (a guaranteed unique string) ?

I.e.

```
class A:

     def __init__(self, key, etc...):
         self.key = key
         ...

     def __hash__(self):
         return self.key.__hash__()

     def __cmp__(self, other):
         return cmp(self.key, other.key)

# then somewhere in code with arr being array of A

unique = sorted(set(arr))
```

Any hint greatly appreciated!

Comment: By the way, `A` should inherit from `object`: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance

Comment: I would write `return hash(self.key)`. Let Python call the underlying special method.

Comment: You're right, I keep forgetting about the 'new style objects'.
Using hash seems good idea, built-ins always surprise me :)

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__). The only requirement of `__hash__` is that it be unique. In fact, this is quite an elegant and Pythonic way of solving the problem!

EDIT: It has been pointed out to me that `__hash__` need not even be unique! Instead, one simply requires equal objects to have the same hash. Unequal ones may *also* have the same hash; in fact, everything could hash to `0` and this would be (technically) fine.

Comment: No, two objects may have the same hash values, so that
   hash(x) == hash(y) and x != y.
That would be perfectly ok.

Comment: It does look pretty, problem is something's not working at the moment :) Sorting this way (seemingly same) two arrays of ~2500 objects yielded two sets of different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Eschew `__cmp__`. [Python3 no longer supports](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) this special method, and recommends using `__lt__` instead.

```
def __lt__(self,other):
    return self.key < self.other
```

Answer (score 2):

Two unequal objects may have the same hash value, but two equal objects may not have different hash values. The law:

```
a == b --> hash(a) == hash(b)
```

describes this. Otherwise you couldn't use them as dict keys or put them is sets. Well, maybe you could add them, but you couldn't retrieve them later.

So, when delegating `__hash__()`, I always define `__eq__()` as well, just to be on the safe side:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.key)

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.key == other.key
```

Since you want to sort your objects, you must also add unutbus `__lt__()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the law I wasn't sure of.